# R split string by special character "+" and categorize the split strings based on conditions

Tags: r, string, stringr

Hello I need to split the strings in `mfn_rate` by the special character with white spaces " + " when it appears, then return the numeric value before it in `mfn_av` and the rest of the string after it in `mfn_spec`

I am trying something like the below:

```
mfn_rate<-c("25%","25% + 2 GBP/tonne","2 GBP per tonne","10%")
mfn_av<-""
mfn_spec<-""
mfn<-data.frame(mfn_rate,mfn_av,mfn_spec)

for (i in 1:nrow(mfn)){
    #if the value in mfn_rate is not a single percentage value, classify it into either mfn_av or mfn_spec
    if(grepl("+",mfn$mfn_rate[i])){
       mfn$mfn_spec[i] <- str_split(mfn$mfn_rate[i],"\\+", "print string after +")
       mfn$mfn_av[i] <- str_split(mfn$mfn_rate[i],"\\+", "print numbers before + sign")
    }
    else ( mfn$mfn_rate[i] <- mfn$mfn_av[i])
}
```

The output should be e.g.:

```
mfn_rate = 25% + 2 GBP/tonne
mfn_av = 25%
mfn_spec = 2 GBP/tonne
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `separate` and `str_detect` within the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mfn_rate<-c("25","25% + 2 GBP/tonne","2 GBP per tonne","10")
mfn <- data.frame(mfn_rate)

mfn <- mfn %>% 
  separate(mfn_rate, c("mfn_av", "mfn_spec"), " \\+ ", remove=F) %>% 
  mutate(mfn_spec = if_else(str_detect(mfn_av, "[:alpha:]"), mfn_av, mfn_spec),
         mfn_av = if_else(str_detect(mfn_av, "[:alpha:]"), NA_character_, mfn_av))
```

Output

```
> mfn
           mfn_rate mfn_av        mfn_spec
1                25     25            <NA>
2 25% + 2 GBP/tonne    25%     2 GBP/tonne
3   2 GBP per tonne   <NA> 2 GBP per tonne
4                10     10            <NA>
```

Comment: I had the same approach, but was not sure whether @melange wanted "2 GBP per tonne" in row 3 to be classified to mfn_spec.

Comment: I agree, it's not clear from the question. If that's the case: add `%>% mutate(mfn_spec = if_else(grepl("GBP", mfn_av), mfn_av, mfn_spec), mfn_av = if_else(grepl("GBP", mfn_av), NA_character_, mfn_av))` at the end of my code.

Comment: Hi thanks! But if there is no numeric (e.g. ```2 GBP per tonne```) it should go to ```mfn_spec``` not to ```mfn_av```

Comment: Hi, is "there is no numeric" the condition you want to classify a string to `mfn_spec`? Because "2 GBP per tonne" contains "2", which is a numeric. Is your condition rather "the string contains "GBP""?

Comment: I mean numeric is just that it is purely numeric characters -> it should be in ```mfn_av```; the GBP is a separate (but perhaps unnecessary condition) for ```mfn_spec```

Comment: If "purely numeric characters -> it should be in `mfn_av`" is your condition, then "25%" which contains "%" and hence is not purely numeric should not be in `mfn_av`. May I suggest you spend some time to very precisely define the conditions for being in `mfn_av` or `mfn_spec`? If you want to program an algorithm, this is absolutely indispensable. The operations must be crystal clear in your head before you can program them. Then try to implement those operations. If you are still stuck, update your question with precise indications or open another post. You can do this!

Comment: Hi yes I am still stuck and apologies by numeric I mean either 25 or 25%.. the logic for me was originally this: how could I split the string via  a special character "+" and then call the split strings to assign them to different columns ```mfn_av``` and ```mfn_spec``` ? Perhaps there is another function for this to use?

Comment: I updated my solution. The condition for being moved to `mfn_spec` is to contain a letter (`str_detect` on [:alpha:]). You can also try to implement yourself other solutions based on `str_split` if you want.